# Distinct table by 2 columns and return all rows

Tags: sql, distinct

I want to get unique fields using distinct on 2 columns (ID and __EventType), however, I have been unsuccessful. Here is my attempt that failed but conceptualizes what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM (select distinct ID, __EventType from SP_HS_Firm_Calendar_All);
```

For example here is All my data:

```
Select ID, __DisplayName, __EventType,EventDate,EndDate from SP_HS_Firm_Calendar_All
```

Returns:
[image]

And here is the data I wish to return using distinct query above: 
[image]

Thank you very much for all your help it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` in most databaes:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id, _eventtype order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT *
FROM SP_HS_Firm_Calendar_All
GROUP BY ID, __EventType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this one:
`Select DISTINCT (ID, __DisplayName) from SP_HS_Firm_Calendar_All`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just `select distinct ID, __EventType from SP_HS_Firm_Calendar_All`?

That alone theoretically should get you all rows with distinct combinations of ID AND __EventType.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution, thank you very much!

```
 select ID, __DisplayName, __EventType,EventDate,EndDate from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id, __EventType order by id) as seqnum from SP_HS_Firm_Calendar_All t) t where seqnum =1
```